# populate php multidimenssional array with foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

I need to create an array like the following:

```
$va_body=array(
    "bundles" => array(
        "$table.$elem" => array("convertCodesToDisplayText" => true),
        "$table.$elem" => array("convertCodesToDisplayText" => true),
    )
);
```

`$table` is a string that does not change and `$elem` is extracted from an array.
I got close with the following code, but it ends up with only the last value from `$bund`, `$bund` is an array with two values. I guess the array is redeclared in each loop?

```
$va_body=array(); // declare the array outside the loop
foreach ($bund as $elem ) {
    $va_body['bundles'] = array($table.".".$elem=>array("convertCodesToDisplayText" => true));
}
```

`$bund` array has two elements "description" and "type_id".

```
$va_body['bundles'][] // Adding [] doesn't work as it modifies the expected outcome.
```

`print_r($va_body)` looks like this:

```
Array (
    [bundles] => Array (
        [ca_objects.type_id] => Array (
            [convertCodesToDisplayText] => 1
            )
        )
    )
```

I need it to be:

```
Array (
    [bundles] => Array (
        [ca_objects.description] => Array (
            [convertCodesToDisplayText] => 1
        )
        [ca_objects.type_id] => Array (
            [convertCodesToDisplayText] => 1
        )
    )
)
```

Thanks in advance.

@phpisuber01
Using:

```
$va_body['bundles'][] = array($table.".".$elem=>array("convertCodesToDisplayText" => true));
```

`print_r($va_body);` looks like this:

```
 Array (
    [bundles] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [ca_objects.description] => Array (
                [convertCodesToDisplayText] => 1
            )
        )
        [1] => Array (
            [ca_objects.type_id] => Array (
                [convertCodesToDisplayText] => 1
            )
        )
    )
)
```

And I need it to be like this:

```
Array (
    [bundles] => Array (
        [ca_objects.description] => Array (
            [convertCodesToDisplayText] => 1
        )
        [ca_objects.type_id] => Array (
            [convertCodesToDisplayText] => 1
        )
    )
)
```

Answer by @phpisuber01:

```
$va_body['bundles'][$table.".".$elem] = array("convertCodesToDisplayText" => true);
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make an array of arrays. In your loop change the following line:

```
$va_body['bundles'][$table.".".$elem] = array("convertCodesToDisplayText" => true);
```

Added `[]` after `$va_body['bundles']`.

All this does is keep adding the new bundles into the array. Your original code is overwriting bundles each iteration. That's why you only get the last one.

Updated to get closer to OP's exact needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I already tried that but It add extra keys to the array I need to get. I modified my question to show yo what happens.

Comment: well... let me tell you that not only it did work. I learned greatly about arrays and finally... I would hug you if you were here!!!! THANKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$va_body = array();
$va_body['bundles'] = array();

foreach ($bund AS $elem)
{
    $va_body['bundles']["{$table}.{$elem}"] = array("convertCodesToDisplayText" => true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!. It happens to be right by the way but I already accepted @phpisuber01 answer.

Comment: No problem, I realized that after posting. Anyway, it's a clean code, so it will probably be useful for someone else :)